# C# refuses to accept generic subclass type

Tags: c#, generics

I keep seeing this error, over and over again:

> Cannot convert from `Item<Foo>` to `Item<IFoo>`.

This is clearly nonsense; an object of type `Item<Foo>` is *statically guaranteed* to be able to do absolutely everything that an `Item<IFoo>` can do (and possibly more), so why is the compiler refusing to accept my perfectly valid code?

I have a method that accepts an `Item<IFoo>` as an argument. For some reason, it refuses to accept an `Item<Foo>` as input, even though `Foo` implements `IFoo`. This makes no sense at all. I can pass a `Foo` in place of an `IFoo`, but I can't pass an `Item<Foo>` in place of an `Item<IFoo>`. Why?

```
public class Item<T>
{
  public readonly int ID;
  public readonly T Data;
  ...
}

public void ProcessItem(Item<IFoo> item)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
}

ProcessItem(new Item<Foo>());
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Sounds like a [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) issue. What version of .NET are you using, and can you show the code that's throwing this error?

Comment: Is `Item` something like List?

Comment: Classes are invariant so you'll have to create an interface.

Comment: `an object of type Item<Foo> is statically guaranteed to be able to do absolutely everything that an Item<IFoo> can do` : Not if an `Item<IFoo>` can "take an `IFoo`" - an `Item<Foo>` can only "take a `Foo`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes in C# are invariant, so depending on your requirements you'll have to create an interface and implment that:

```
public interface IItem<out T> { ... }
public class Item<T> : IItem<T> { ... }

IItem<IFoo> item = new Item<Foo>();
```

Note that it is not necessarily safe to assign a `Class<Subtype>` to a `Class<Basetype>`. A common example is `List<T>`:

```
List<object> l = new List<string>();   //won't compile
l.Add(3);
```

C# only allows variance annotations on interfaces and delegates, and only when it is safe to do so.

Comment: I suppose the "correct" solution here is to drop generics completely and just hard-code the parameter to always be `IFoo`... I had assumed that generics works sanely. I guess not.